# How can I prevent certain instances of a instance geometry from disappearing when center position no longer in view?

Tags: three.js

I'm learning webgl, threejs and glsl shaders. The scene you see below is my attempt at working with instanced geometry. I have 3 patches of "grass". The grass is actually made of instanced cones around the central position of the mesh I'm building.

As you can see, if the central position (marked with a white wireframe cone) of the mesh is no longer in the camera view, all instances disappear.

[image: flickering bug]

How can I prevent this?

And to be even more specific: Are all the grass patches, or all fire instances, or all particles of the same time supposed to be instanced at once and place around the scene how we see fit? My assumption is that they should. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `InstancedBufferGeometry`, there are two ways you can deal with frustum culling.

One way is to turn frustum culling off for the mesh:

```
mesh.frustumCulled = false;
```

The other option is to set the bounding sphere of the mesh's geometry manually, if it is known in your case:

```
geometry.boundingSphere = new THREE.Sphere( new THREE.Vector3(), radius );
```

three.js r.88

Comment: that was it! Thanks! frustumCulled is the way to go as I will have custom logic that decides what to show on the screen!